# Call property of a function from within another function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
var Apple = function() {
    this.hello = 'alrightalrightalright';
}

var Banana = function() {
    this.howdy = 'matthew mcconaughhey';
        console.log(a.hello); // returns 'alrightalrightalright';
}

var a = new Apple();
var b = new Banana();
```

In the code above (which is a simplified form of what I already have), I want to call the `hello` property of the `Apple` function from within the `Banana` function. Obviously I can do this by `a.hello` from within the `Banana` function, since `a` is an instance of `Apple`. However, this might be error-prone in later stages when you revisit the code.

Is there a way I can reference the `hello` property of the `Apple` function from another function without referencing the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question literally, no with the way you've coded the `Apple` object, you cannot access the `hello` property without an instance of the `Apple` object.

The `hello` property only exists on an instance of the `Apple` object so you must have an instance of that object in order to be able to reference that property as in `a.hello`.

---

You can redesign where the `hello` property is stored such that you can access it with an instance of the `Apple` object, but that means changing where the property is defined.

For example, it can be made a static variable (which is not a property of any specific `Apple` object) by defining it like this:

```
var Apple = function() {

}

Apple.hello = 'alrightalrightalright';
```

Then, you can reference it like this:

```
var Banana = function() {
    this.howdy = 'matthew mcconaughhey';
    console.log(Apple.hello); // returns 'alrightalrightalright';
}

var b = new Banana();
```

But, keep in mind that this changes the behavior of the `hello` property.  It is now not a separate property of each `Apple` object.  Instead it's essentially a single global property on the `Apple` function object.  It only has one value, no matter how many instances of `Apple` you have and you can reference it inside an `Apple` object using `this.hello` because it isn't a property of each `Apple` object any more.  All references to it would need to be `Apple.hello`.

---

In the end, you need to decide if this is really supposed to be a property of the `Apple` object that could possibly have a unique value for each separate `Apple` object or if this is really just a `static` variable that you can just define once and reference that one definition from anywhere.

Comment: That last line is actually a very valid point @jfriend00. Just wondering, is there anything I could do with the `.call` or `.apply` method?

Comment: @AKG - `.call()` and `.apply()` don't have anything to do with this issue.  Those are for controlling the value of the `this` pointer and controlling function arguments when calling methods on some object.  `this.hello` is a property, not a method.  Nothing to do with `.call()` and `.apply()` here.

Comment: @jfried00 thanks for pointing that out. I stumbled on that but I couldn't make heads or tails of it. Still learning ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a static property.

```
var Apple = function() {
};
Apple.hello = 'alrightalrightalright';

var Banana = function() {
    this.howdy = 'matthew mcconaughhey';
        console.log(Apple.hello); // returns 'alrightalrightalright';
};
```

Comment: Still he can access it with `Apple.hello` only

Comment: Yes, but he said he wants to access it without referencing the instance.